# Callbacks in iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Hello is it possible to make a callback like such? I want to pass a function as a parameter to be able run the callback function after some task is finished.

```
class ConnectBLE {
    var callBackFunc: ()->()

    init(callFunc: @escaping () -> ()){

        callBackFunc = callFunc
    }

    func runCallBackFunc() {
        callBackFunc()
    }
}
class DelegateARC {
    private let object = ConnectBLE(callFunc: RaspakHC05)

    func RaspakHC05() {
        print("hello from a callback")
    }
}
```

But I'm having an error. 
***Cannot convert value of type '(DelegateARC) -> () -> ()' to expected argument type '() -> ()'***

Comment: Why would the print message come out? There is no call to the callback?

Comment: @Rob it does not compile.

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't reference `self` in a non-lazy property initializer, as they are run before your object is initialized.  Try: `private lazy var object: ConnectBLE = ConnectBLE(callFunc: self.RaspakHC05)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way (use Optional to delay giving `object` its real value until initialization has otherwise fully taken place):

```
class ConnectBLE {
    var callBackFunc: ()->()

    init(callFunc: @escaping () -> ()){

        callBackFunc = callFunc
    }

    func runCallBackFunc() {
        callBackFunc()
    }
}
class DelegateARC {
    private var object : ConnectBLE! //*

    init() {
        self.object = ConnectBLE(callFunc: RaspakHC05) // *
    }

    func RaspakHC05() {
        print("hello from a callback")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run non-lazy code on the top level of the class which requires `self` (`RaspakHC05`).

Apart from that you have to call `runCallBackFunc()` in `ConnectBLE` somewhere to execute the closure.

You could do (in a Playground)

```
class ConnectBLE {
    var callBackFunc: ()->()

    init(callFunc: @escaping () -> ()){
        callBackFunc = callFunc
    }

    func runCallBackFunc() {
        callBackFunc()
    }
}
class DelegateARC {

    init() {
        ConnectBLE(callFunc: RaspakHC05).runCallBackFunc()
    }

    func RaspakHC05() {
        print("hello from a callback")
    }
}


DelegateARC() // prints "hello from a callback"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a `function` instead a `closure`. You have to use a `closure` and `lazy instantiation` to make it work:

```
class DelegateARC {
    private lazy var object: ConnectBLE = {
        return ConnectBLE(callFunc: self.RaspakHC05)
    }()

    var RaspakHC05: () -> () {
        return {
            print("hello from a callback")
        }
    }
}
```