# Callback syntax in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, closures

I am trying to create a callback on swift 3 but haven't had any luck so far. I was taking a look at this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527861/callbacks-in-ios-swift-3) which is similar, but the answer gives me an error.

Basically I have an API struct with a static function that I need to have a callback.

```
import UIKit

struct API {
 public static func functionWithCallback(params: Dictionary<String, String>, success: @escaping ((_ response: String) -> Ticket), failure: @escaping((_ error:String) -> String) ) {
        let app_server_url = "http://api.com" + params["key"]!

        let url: URL = URL(string: app_server_url)!
        var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        do {
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        request.addValue("application/json charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
                    print(json)
                    var message = ""

                    if let result = json["result"] as? String {
                        if(result == "success") {
                            //attempt to call callback gives me an error: extra argument in call
                            success("") {
                               let ticket = json["ticket"] as! NSDictionary
                               var date = ticket["date"] as! String
                               var ticket: Ticket = nil
                               ticket.setDate(date: date)
                               return ticket
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                        message = json["message"] as! String
                        print(message)
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                    let description = error.localizedDescription
                    if let data = description.data(using: .utf8) {
                        do {
                            let jsonError = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                            let message = jsonError?["message"] as! String
                        } catch {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

So I basically can't call the callback success because it gives me an error: Extra argument in call. Any idea on how to fix it?

My goal is to call:

```
API.functionWithCallback(params: params, success() -> Ticket {
    //do something with the returned ticket here
},
error() -> () {
   //do something with the error message here
}
)
```

Comment: There are tons of errors.

Comment: There might be. I edited the question within the browser to remove unnecessary code, but it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have it wrong on how to use call back closures, from what I can understand of your question you want to do something with the ticket in the call back closure and to do that it should be a parameter of the closure not the return type of the closure.

Replace your function declaration with this:

```
public static func functionWithCallback(params: Dictionary<String, String>, success: @escaping ((_ response: String, _ ticket: Ticket) -> Void), failure: @escaping((_ error:String) -> Void) ) {
```

And inside the function replace this:

```
success("") {
    let ticket = json["ticket"] as! NSDictionary
    var date = ticket["date"] as! String
    var ticket: Ticket = nil // Im not sure what you are trying to do with this line but this will definitely give an error
    ticket.setDate(date: date)
    return ticket
}
```

With:

```
let ticket = json["ticket"] as! NSDictionary
var date = ticket["date"] as! String
var ticket: Ticket = nil // fix this line
ticket.setDate(date: date)
success("",ticket)
```

And then you can call the function like this:

```
API.functionWithCallback(params: params, success: { response, ticket in
    // you can use ticket here
    // and also the response text 
}) { errorMessage in
    // use the error message here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I am looking for! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
func uploadImage(api: String,token : String, methodType : String,  requestDictionary: [String:AnyObject],picData:[Data], successHandler: @escaping (AnyObject) -> Void,failureHandler: @escaping (NSError) -> Void)
{

    if Common_Methods.Reachability1.isConnectedToNetwork() == false
    {

        let del :AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!

        let nav : UINavigationController = (del.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)!

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "The Internet connection appears to be offline" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // Create the actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in

        }

        alert.addAction(okAction)
        nav.present( alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    let apiUrl = "\(KbaseUrl)\(api)"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: apiUrl as String)!
    print(url)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = methodType
    let boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449") as String

    //-------- add token as perameter and set a check if token not nill then set token in header -------


    if(token.characters.count > 0)
    {
        request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-logintoken")
    }

    request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let data = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: requestDictionary, filePathKey:nil, imageDataKey: picData.count > 0 ? picData : [], boundary: boundary)
    print(data)
    request.httpBody = data

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in

        // handle fundamental network errors (e.g. no connectivity)

        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            successHandler(data as AnyObject )//completion(data as AnyObject?, error as NSError?)
            print(error)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Common_Methods.hideHUD(view: (topVC?.view)!)
            }
            return
        }

        // check that http status code was 200

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse , httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {





            do {
                let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary


                if let responseDictionary = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject]
                {
                    if responseDictionary["statusCode"] as! Int == 401
                    {

                        // self.objDelegate.sessionExpire(msgStr: "Session Expired. Please login again to continue.")




                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //completion(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as AnyObject?, nil)

                    }

                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    Common_Methods.hideHUD(view: (topVC?.view)!)
                }
                //  completion(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as AnyObject?, nil)
            }



        }

        // parse the JSON response

        do {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Common_Methods.hideHUD(view: (topVC?.view)!)
            }
            let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
            successHandler(responseObject! )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Common_Methods.hideHUD(view: (topVC?.view)!)
            }
            //  completion(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as AnyObject?, error)
            failureHandler(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    //  return task


}
```

and function Call is :

```
WebService.sharedInstance.uploadImage(api: KEditEmployerProfile,token: token,methodType: "PUT", requestDictionary: parameters1 as! [String : AnyObject], picData: [imageData as Data], successHandler: { (responseObject) in
 print(responseObject)
    }) { (error) in
                print(error)
        }
      }
```